# Output UTF-8 Encoded File

Tags: file, utf-8, character-encoding, lua, export

I use Lua within [REAPER](http://reaper.fm), an audio recording/mixing software with scripting capabilities.

I succeed to write file in ANSI from it from a script execution, using the standard i/o model.

How could I write/output a UTF-8 encoded file ?

I don't see anything about that in the documentation.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you mean ASCII when you said "ANSI"? Or are you talking about some kind of Windows codepage?

Comment: Hi, according to my research, it seems that ANSI is in fact as nickname for Windows-1252. but when you use Notepad++ or Notepad, it tells me that the output file is ANSI.
Because this doesn't support some UTF-8 characters (é, è, à etc...) I need my file to be wirtten directly in UTF-8. Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can access to a Linux system, maybe you can try `iconv` command, which allows you to perform that kind of conversions.

This task could be easily done by writting:

```
iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 -t UTF-8  ANSI_file > UTF-8_file
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer !
Unfortunately, I need this script to be executed from Windows and From Mac (there is no REAPER linux version).
Also, because I think it would be better to have a way to directly write in UTF-8, so that UTF-8 characters don't get lost in the process.

Comment: I guess that there is a `iconv` command for Mac, which probably uses the same syntax that in Linux.  For Windows it seems that there is a version of the same software (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm). About writting directly a UTF-8 encoded file, I'm sorry I cannot help.

Comment: Thanks, I will inspect that solution. Cheers !